# Exception reading response

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

[image]

I created an java stand alone application to send an email to gmail using smtp Everything fine with running it in eclipse. But i uploaded it in the bpm and using it as java integration service to send an email but it was showing an error is:::-Exception reading response.
please help me with this..

Comment: We will need to know a more specific error message to help you.

Comment: IBM BPM has server logs, look here and then you will see exact error message